# Using R to change data frame to suitable heatmap matrix

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap

I apologize if this is a poorly asked question.  This is my first ask on StackOverflow.

I have usage data on applications that I am trying to turn into a heatmap to show overlapping using among users across applications.  I am having difficulty getting the data into the format that works well for visualizing a heatmap in corrplot (my preferred heatmap visualization package).

Data is formatted so each possible combination of app usage is represented as a row (e.g. app1 alone, app2 alone, app1+app2, app3 alone, app1+app3, app2+app3, app1+app2+app3 etc.) with the corresponding number of users who fall into that particular configuration of app usage (e.g. someone who has only ever used app1 and app3 would contribute 1 to that particular row).

Example starting data with the apps:

```
df.start <- data.frame(appset = c("[app1]","[app2]","[app3]","[app1;app2]","[app2;app3]","[app1;app3]","[app1;app2;app3"]),
                       unique_users = c(1000, 400, 150, 300, 30, 130,10))
```

I want to ultimate get the data into a form with the following properties:
1) Each row and column represents one of the apps (like a correlation matrix) so for a 3 app set it should be a 3x3 matrix where the rows are 'app1' 'app2' 'app3' and the columns are also 'app1' 'app2' 'app3'
2) Each row is normalized by the total number of users for the app on that row so that the numbers represent a ratio of column.app/row.app telling us what percentage of users who use the row app also use the column app (if easier to normalize by columns, this is also fine)

My aim is for it look something like this:

```
df.end <- data.frame(app1 = c(1, 310/1440, 140/1440),
                     app2 = c(310/740, 1, 40/740),
                     app3 = c(140/320, 40/320, 1))
row.names(df.end) <- c('app1','app2','app3')
```

(I kept included the numbers as a ratio like '300/1430' to demonstrate the kind of calculation I want done on each row to normalize the data but ultimately the value should just appear as .20979 in that instance; how it will appear in R by running that code is how I would like it to appear)

I'm not married to getting the data in that form, I ultimately just need a way to visualize the relationship of cross-usage across the apps and a heatmap has served me well for these purposes in the past.  What I do need are:
1) Automatic detection of the apps in the data using their names to generate the rows and columns of the matrix (since I have more than just the 3 example apps and would like to rerun the code on various combinations of apps of interest for different purposes)
2) Numbers represented as ratio between apps such that both directions are represented somewhere in the data (e.g. ratio of app1 users who also use app2 as well as ratio of app2 users who also use app1).

I've done calculations of individual cells by hand (with copying and pasting into excel of the results to match the form I need) but this is clearly a poor approach for reproducible results and application to new data sets.

To separate the app sets into columns I started by:

```
df.start <- mutate(df.start, 
                   app1 = ifelse(grepl("app1", df.start$appset),TRUE,FALSE),
                   app2 = ifelse(grepl("app2", df.start$appset),TRUE,FALSE),
                   app3 = ifelse(grepl("app3", df.start$appset),TRUE,FALSE))
```

Finding the total sum of unique users for each user (for normalizing rows later):

```
total_app1 <- sum(df.start$unique_users[df.start$app1])
total_app2 <- sum(df.start$unique_users[df.start$app2])
total_app3 <- sum(df.start$unique_users[df.start$app3])
```

And then generating the individual cells of normalized data by hand to copy and paste into excel:

```
sum(df.start$unique_users[df.start$app1 & df.start$app1])/total_app1
sum(df.start$unique_users[df.start$app1 & df.start$app2])/total_app1
sum(df.start$unique_users[df.start$app1 & df.start$app3])/total_app1

sum(df.start$unique_users[df.start$app2 & df.start$app1])/total_app2
sum(df.start$unique_users[df.start$app2 & df.start$app2])/total_app2
sum(df.start$unique_users[df.start$app2 & df.start$app3])/total_app2

sum(df.start$unique_users[df.start$app3 & df.start$app1])/total_app3
sum(df.start$unique_users[df.start$app3 & df.start$app2])/total_app3
sum(df.start$unique_users[df.start$app3 & df.start$app3])/total_app3
```

Obviously not how it should be done if I want to have an automated process for data sets that include other apps, but if it helps explain what I'm attempted I wanted to include what I've been doing thus far.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Left out an important detail in the sample data that sets of apps can be more than two (e.g. a row exists for users who used exactly all three apps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing heavily from Feng but with a few critical changes, here is code to accomplish my problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# Starting with the data
df.start <- data.frame(appset = c("[app1]","[app2]","[app3]","[app1;app2]","[app2;app3]","[app1;app3]","[app1;app2;app3]"),
                       unique_users = c(1000, 400, 150, 300, 30, 130,10))

# Remove [ ] and " characters first
df.start$appset <- as.character(df.start$appset) %>%
                   str_replace_all('\\[','') %>%
                   str_replace_all('\\]','') %>%
                   str_replace_all('\"','')

# Get unique names of the apps and alphabetize
apps <- df.start$appset %>%
        str_split(';') %>%
        unlist() %>%
        unique() %>%
        sort(decreasing = FALSE)

# Calculate the matrix of overlapping usage
apps.mat <- sapply(apps, function(m) sapply(apps, function(n) sum(df.start$unique_users[grepl(m,df.start$appset) & grepl(n,df.start$appset)])))
# This is the first critical change needed - this approach deals with any
# number of possible apps and combinations of those apps (not just if they 
# are initially reported in pairs.

# Normalize each row by diagonal (e.g. combined usage / total usage per app)  
apps.mat.norm <- sweep(apps.mat,1,diag(apps.mat),'/')
# Second critical change is switching the margin in sweep to 1 (rows) and 
# the stat to diag().  This way each row is normalized by the overlap
# of the apps usage to itself (i.e. total unique users in that app
# regardless of other app usage).  The diagonal should represent 100% 
# overlap between an app and itself.
```

I think a couple of the changes I needed to make were because I explained the problem poorly.  I apologize for that but definitely appreciate the immense help in dealing with several of the data management problems I was having!

Answer (score 1):

OK...seems that I got what you want to do after the long reading. It is mainly a problem about data cleaning, and the major task is to get the right matrix for your corplot. Let's start with your `df.start`.

```
require(stringr) #To handle the app names.
require(magrittr) #Pipe operator.

df.start$appset <- as.character(df.start$appset) %>% str_replace_all('\\[','') %>% str_replace_all('\\[','')
# Remove the annoying '[' and ']' first.

apps <- df.start$appset %>% str_split(';') %>% unlist() %>% unique()
# Get the names of all your apps.

apps.self <- paste(apps,apps,sep = ';')
df.start$appset[match(apps,df.start$appset)] <- apps.self
# Change 'app1' to 'app1;app1' format. 

appset.swap <- sapply(df.start$appset,function(x){paste(rev(unlist(str_split(x,';'))),collapse = ';')})
# Swap the app1;app2 to app2;app1. 

df.start <- rbind(df.start,data.frame(appset = appset.swap,unique_users = df.start$unique_users,row.names = NULL)) %>% unique()
# Assign values to the swapped appset, and merge with df.start. Now the dataframe looks much better.

df.start <- df.start[order(df.start$appset),]
mat <- matrix(df.start$unique_users,nrow = length(apps),ncol = length(apps))
# Arrange your appset alphabetically, and make the matrix.

mat <- sweep(mat,2,colSums(mat),'/')
diag(mat) <- 1
rownames(mat) <- apps
colnames(mat) <- apps
df.end <- as.data.frame(mat)
#Done.
```

I'm a little confused that why the diagonal should be 1. The information of single app user will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for this!  There is a lot of good stuff here that will be very useful for the final solution.One thing I should have made clearer: the app sets don't just happen in pairs.  For example, an app set could be ["app1;app2;app3"].

Comment: In the end, the diagonal needs to be 1 simply for the heatmap data.  We don't care to know how many users who used app1 also used app1, we know that will always be 100%.  If it retained information about raw counts of users who used app1, this would be more informative but would mess with the color gradient of the heatmap.

Comment: To go from the format I have to a matrix, turns out I just needed nested sapply calls like the following: `sapply(apps, function(m) sapply(apps, function(n) sum(df.start$unique_users[grepl(m,df.start$appset) & grepl(n,esets3$appset)])))`